# Get last modified date when left join on two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have Main table **advertiser** and want to do left join two table **LayoutVariables** and **LayoutMapping** on advertiser_id and get last modified date in this two tables column in final result.

And this below query giving only one record, i want all the values from **advertiser** table even if no date value in this two tables **LayoutVariables** and **LayoutMapping**

```
SELECT  
    ADV.av_id,
    ADV.av_advertiser_name,
    ADV.av_is_active, 
    IF(AVLV.alv_advertiser_id IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS isBrandConfigDone,
    IF(AVLM.alm_advertiser_id IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS isLayoutMappingDone,
   ---here i want the max date between two tables
    IF(AVLM.alm_last_modified_on IS NOT NULL AND AVLV.alv_last_modified_on IS NOT NULL,IF(MAX(AVLM.alm_last_modified_on)>MAX(AVLV.alv_last_modified_on), "AVLM", "AVLV"),NULL) AS mm
    FROM DB.Advertiser AS ADV 
    LEFT JOIN DB.LayoutVariables AS AVLV ON ADV.av_id = AVLV.alv_advertiser_id
    LEFT JOIN DB.LayoutMapping AS AVLM ON ADV.av_id = AVLM.alm_advertiser_id 
    WHERE ADV.av_is_active=1;
```

Table LayoutVariable

| alv_id | alv_advertiser_id | alv_layout_variable_key | alv_layout_variable_value | alv_last_modified_on | alv_last_modified_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 8167 | var4 | var val 40 | 1624550014 | 2025 |
| 12 | 7690 | amazon_usa | amazon_usa_vairaible | 1624589928 | 2021 |

Table LayOutmapping

| alm_id | alm_advertiser_id | alm_layout_id | alm_last_modified_on | alm_last_modified_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 8167 | 334455 | 1624436972 | 2025 |
| 12 | 7690 | 123 | 1624320000 | 2021 |

Table Advertiser

| av_id | av_advertiser_name | av_is_active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8167 | TestAdvertiser | 1 |
| 7690 | amazon_usa | 1 |

```
CREATE TABLE LayoutVariable (
 alv_id INT,alv_advertiser_id INT,alv_layout_variable_key VARCHAR(200),
 alv_layout_variable_value VARCHAR(200),alv_last_modified_on INT,alv_last_modified_by INT);

INSERT INTO LayoutVariable VALUES
 (11,8167,'var4','var val 40',1624550014,2025),
 (12,7690,'amazon_usa','amazon_usa_vairaible',1624589928,2021);

CREATE TABLE LayOutmapping (    
alm_id INT,alm_advertiser_id INT,alm_layout_id INT,
alm_last_modified_on INT,alm_last_modified_by INT);

INSERT INTO LayOutmapping VALUES
 (5  ,8167 ,334455 ,1624436972 ,2025)
 (12  ,7690 ,123 ,1624320000 ,2021);

CREATE TABLE Advertiser (
av_id INT,av_advertiser_name VARCHAR(200),av_is_active INT);

INSERT INTO Advertiser VALUES
(8167,'TestAdvertiser',1),
(7690,'amazon_usa',1);
```

Can someone guide me here

Comment: Use correlated subqueries in the output list.

Comment: can you show some example for the above requirement

Comment: Provide sample data for related tables and show desired results.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Provided, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do like this:

```
SELECT
    ADV.av_id,
    ADV.av_advertiser_name,
    ADV.av_is_active, 
    AVLV.alv_advertiser_id ,
    AVLM.alm_advertiser_id ,
    IF(AVLV.alv_advertiser_id IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS isBrandConfigDone,
    IF(AVLM.alm_advertiser_id IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS isLayoutMappingDone,
    (SELECT MAX(lmd) FROM 
            (SELECT alm_last_modified_on lmd FROM LayoutMapping UNION
             SELECT alv_last_modified_on FROM LayoutVariables) v) AS mm
    FROM Advertiser AS ADV 
    LEFT JOIN LayoutVariables AS AVLV ON ADV.av_id = AVLV.alv_advertiser_id
    LEFT JOIN LayoutMapping AS AVLM ON ADV.av_id = AVLM.alm_advertiser_id 
;
```

OR with the same subquery in the `SELECT` list, make it as a `CROSS JOIN` like:

```
SELECT
    ADV.av_id,
    ADV.av_advertiser_name,
    ADV.av_is_active, 
    AVLV.alv_advertiser_id ,
    AVLM.alm_advertiser_id ,
    IF(AVLV.alv_advertiser_id IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS isBrandConfigDone,
    IF(AVLM.alm_advertiser_id IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS isLayoutMappingDone,
    mm
    FROM Advertiser AS ADV 
    LEFT JOIN LayoutVariables AS AVLV ON ADV.av_id = AVLV.alv_advertiser_id
    LEFT JOIN LayoutMapping AS AVLM ON ADV.av_id = AVLM.alm_advertiser_id 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(lmd) AS mm FROM 
            (SELECT alm_last_modified_on lmd FROM LayoutMapping UNION
             SELECT alv_last_modified_on FROM LayoutVariables) v) mx
```

Your attempt originally using `MAX()` on the whole query whereas these methods above are a subquery that is separated from the rest of the query.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4bcf9a1f2085aaab5848a4d69d6bf6a6)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer,  i have run above query, which is giving mm for the all the rows, this value 1624589928 is coming for other rows as well

Comment: no, only for matching rows mm shd come, for not matchin it shd come null

Comment: You mean like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=532172d1034587c84b1dff5693bd7aaa

Comment: yea, but for 8167, this value 1624550014 in LayoutVariables table is greater than value in LayoutMapping and in ur query , it is coming null, null shd come if no values present for av_id's

Comment: Ok, how about this then? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3937b412f823440d5dfe9b281b1c9ab